# Where does LINQ overload Console.WriteLine() for it's IEnumerable<T> result

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
var products1 = new List<Product> {
     new Product { Name = "Apple", Price = 2 }};

var products2 = from product in products1
      select new { product.Name, product.Price };

foreach (var p in products1) 
      Console.WriteLine(p);

foreach (var p in products2)
      Console.WriteLine(p);
```

Why second one prints "{ Name = Apple, Price = 2 }"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why second one prints "{ Name = Apple, Price = 2 }"?

Because you created an anonymous type using `new` keyword, its not same as `Product` type.

Since you call `Console.WriteLine(p);` that is equivalent to:

```
Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
```

You may see: [C#/.NET Little Wonders: The Joy of Anonymous Types](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/06/21/c.net-little-wonders-the-joy-of-anonymous-types.aspx)

> **ToString() on Anonymous Types**
>
> One of the more trivial overrides that an anonymous type provides you
>   is a ToString() method that **prints the value of the anonymous type
>   instance in much the same format as it was initialized** (except
>   actual values instead of expressions as appropriate of course).

Answer (score 2):

You're creating an anonymous type which implements its own `ToString` method.

Answer (score 1):

This is not LINQ, it's how the C# compiler generates `ToString` for anonymous types.